# Send email using Office 365 using unified API

Tags: ms-office, office365, office365api

We are trying to use the O365 Unified API to send emails from our line-of-business apps. I use the following code to send the email. This throws a **DataServiceQueryException exception "Unauthorized"**.

```
public async Task SendEmailAsUserAsync(EmailMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        var graphClient = await _authenticationHelper.GetGraphClientAsync();
        Message m = InitializeMessage(message);
        await graphClient.Me.SendMailAsync(m, true);
    }
    catch (DataServiceQueryException dsqe)
    {
        _logger.Error("Could not get files: " + dsqe.InnerException.Message, dsqe);
        throw;
    }
}

private static Message InitializeMessage(EmailMessage message)
{
    ItemBody body = new ItemBody {Content = message.Body, ContentType = BodyType.HTML};
    Message m = new Message
    {
        Body = body,
        Subject = message.Subject,
        Importance = Importance.Normal,
    };
    //Add all the to email ids
    if (message.ToRecipients != null)
        foreach (Models.Messaging.EmailAddress emailAddress in message.ToRecipients)
        {
            m.ToRecipients.Add(new Recipient { EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress { Address = emailAddress.Address, Name = emailAddress.Name } });
        }
    return m;
}
```

The code for _authenticationHelper.GetGraphClientAsync() is

```
public async Task<GraphService> GetGraphClientAsync()
{
    Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(appConfig.GraphResourceUriBeta + appConfig.Tenant);
    _graphClient = new GraphService(serviceRoot,
        async () => await AcquireTokenAsyncForUser(appConfig.GraphResourceUri, appConfig.Tenant));
    return _graphClient;
}

private async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsyncForUser(string resource, string tenantId)
{
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await GetAccessToken(resource, tenantId);
    _accessCode = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    return _accessCode;
}

private async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAccessToken(string resource, string tenantId)
{
    string authority = appConfig.Authority;
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(appConfig.ClientId, appConfig.ClientSecret);
    string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    string userAccessToken = authHeader.Substring(authHeader.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim();
    UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userAccessToken);
    var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential, userAssertion);
    return authenticationResult;
}
```

However if I change the SendEmailAsUserAsync method as shown below, the email is sent but an **InvalidOperationException is thrown with message "The complex type 'System.Object' has no settable properties."**

```
public async Task SendEmailAsUserAsync(EmailMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        var graphClient = await _authenticationHelper.GetGraphClientAsync();
        Message m = InitializeMessage(message);
        //await graphClient.Me.SendMailAsync(m, true); //This did not work
        var user = await graphClient.Me.ExecuteAsync();
        await user.SendMailAsync(m, true);
    }
    catch (DataServiceQueryException dsqe)
    {
        _logger.Error("Could not get files: " + dsqe.InnerException.Message, dsqe);
        throw;
    }  
}
```

Can any one point out if there is something wrong here.

Comment: I have currently solved my immediate need by using regular O365 API and AppOnly permissions using a certificate. Would greatly appreciate it if someone can help with this issue though

Answer (score 0):

Check the example project below, this has a working example (after you fill in the ClientID etc. in app.config).

[Office 365 API demo applications](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Office365Api.Overview)

For sending email it uses the function below, which works if you set it up correctly. It also has a number of functions for Authenticating using [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx).

```
    public async Task SendMail(string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        var client = await this.AuthenticationHelper
            .EnsureOutlookServicesClientCreatedAsync(
            Office365Capabilities.Mail.ToString());

        Message mail = new Message();
        mail.ToRecipients.Add(new Recipient() 
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = to,
            }
        });
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = new ItemBody() { Content = body, ContentType = BodyType.HTML };

        await client.Me.SendMailAsync(mail, true);
    }
```

Comment: Your sample uses outlookclient and not the unified api with graphservice, although quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no assembly wrapper for the graph API.

[Microsoft.Graph.dll](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) is deprecrated.

So, you should to :

1. Deal with the REST requests : See here : http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_send
2. Generate a wrapper with Microsoft.Vipr project : see here : https://github.com/microsoft/vipr

For the authentication, ADAL works fine :)